# Difference between Spring MVC formatters and converters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, converters, formatter

I would need some clarification regarding the **difference** between Spring MVC **formatters** and **converters**.

My understanding of the main difference between them is that the **formatter works on data that is going to be displayed to the end user** such as a date, SSN or credit card number **whereas the converter works on data hidden behind form controls** such as the value attribute of an select's option.

Am I right or wrong? Can someone please provide advice and/or samples in order to better explain the difference between the two.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Converters* are used to convert one Java type to another Java type. For example, from `Long` to `java.util.Date` or from `Integer` to `Color` or from `String` to `Date`. It can be used in the web tier or any other tier that needs conversion service.

*Formatters* are used to convert `String` to another Java type and back. So, one type must be `String`. You **cannot**, for example, write a formatter that converts a `Long` to a `Date`. Examples of formatters are `DateFormatter`, for parsing `String` to `java.util.Date` and formatting a `Date`. In addition, formatters' messages can be localized.

**Conclusion**: formatters are suitable in the web environment, such as a Spring MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Converter components are used for converting one type to another type and also to provide a cleaner separation by forcing to place all such conversion related code in one single place.

Spring already supports built-in converters for the commonly used types and the framework is extensible enough for writing custom converters as well.

Spring Formatters come into picture to format the data according to the display where it is rendered. Examples may include formatting date/timestamp values according to locales etc.

Comment: I also don´t exactly know the difference. For example, you can write Date to String converter, and in will behave like formatter. Also, Formatter has parse method to do conversion from String to Date... So what is the main difference, if they can substitute each other?

Comment: Thank you Jigar Parekh, however you don't really answer my question (by the way, I did read the article you quote).

Comment: I like the comment by B.Gen.Jack.O.Neill: the way he puts the question is perhaps clearer than my original question. Can someone please answer his question.